# Search box doesn't appear in the right corner

Tags: bug, help-center, search-box

According to the title, the search box doesn't appear in the right corner of every page. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) under "How do I search?" states:

> Enter search terms in the search box that appears in the **upper right corner** of every page, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However, the search box appears in the center of every page instead of the upper right corner:

[image: Screenshot showing search box location]

Comment: Your red free hand circles look a bit squared today ...

Comment: Clearly it's in the centre upper right.

Comment: I'd say it is on the upper right corner of the left half of the screen.

Comment: "right" refers to "correct" here. While all other elements are somehow in the upper wrong corner, the search box is in the right corner.